# How many different individuals have been Robin?

Tags: dc, robin, teen-titans

After seeing the new Justice League vs Teen Titans I googled Damian to see when he was born and who his mother is. In the Wiki article I remember reading that Damien is the 5th Robin, but I thought that there was only Dick Grayson and Jason Todd.

How many characters have assumed the role of Robin?

Comment: What do you mean by "played Robin?"

Comment: @RogueJedi - I think he means "**How many [different Robins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_(comics)) have there been?**" (e.g. Dick Grayson, Jason Todd, Tim Drake, Stephanie Brown, Damian Wayne, Helena Wayne, Carrie Kelley, etc etc)

Comment: In that case, do What If? and *Elseworlds* Robins count?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about any/all continuities?

Comment: @phantom42 - If the answer to that question is "yes", then the answer just got a thousand times longer. Everyone and his dog has been Robin over the years including the Joker and Batman himself.

Comment: How has this question never been asked before?

Comment: @phantom42 i mean total. not asking only about a specific continuity

Comment: What about the new 'We Are... Robin' story arch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main continuity, 5 individuals have assumed the role of Robin:

**Dick Grayson**

[image: grayson]

a young acrobat whose parents are murdered. He is taken in by Bruce Wayne and trained to fight crime as Robin. Dick grows up and drops the Robin identity and creates a new one, Nightwing, to escape living in Batman's shadow.

---

**Jason Todd**

[image: todd]

a street orphan caught stealing the tires off of the Batmobile. Batman offers him the now vacant role of Robin after he helps Batman catch some robbers. Jason Todd is killed by the Joker and then eventually replaced. Years later he returns as the Red Hood.

---

**Tim Drake**

[image: drake]

a boy with incredible detective skills who deduces the identities of Batman and Robin. Batman even acknowledges that someday Tim will surpass his own detective skills. He later shifts into the role of Red Robin.

---

**Stephanie Brown**

[image: brown]

Tim Drake's girlfriend who also was the Spoiler fills in for a short time after Drake resigns. This was retconned out for the New 52 continuity.

---

**Damian Wayne**

[image: wayne]

the son of Bruce Wayne and Talia al Ghul. After Batman's apparent death in Final Crisis, Dick Grayson takes on the role of Batman and places Damian as his Robin. Eventually, Bruce returns and Dick goes back to his Nightwing persona but Damian stays Robin.

---

If we are including elseworld stories, I wouldn't even know where to begin except to note **Carrie Kelley** from the Dark Knight Returns as the most prominent portrayal.

Comment: If you count  Carrie Kelley, then why not Bruce Wayne and Talon??

Comment: I don't count Carrie Kelley. I simply said that Carrie Kelley is the most prominent elseworld portrayal.

Comment: Bruce Wayne should certainly be on the list.   In one story he created the Robin persona while training.  This is official DC pre-crisis continuity, not elseworlds, nor a hoax, dream or imaginary story, albeit fairly obscure.   article:  https://www.cbr.com/bruce-wayne-robin-before-batman/     sample image :   https://static1.cbrimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/detective-comics-226-2.jpg?q=50&fit=crop&w=750&dpr=1.5